# Recognize PS5 Dualsense controller models from the box

Tags: controllers, ps5

Recently while researching the Dualsense analog stick drift common issue I have read some comments pointing out that at least two different joystick versions exist: the original one and a later reworked model that apparently has some minor hardware improvement.

Based on said info recognizing the two models is quite easy done by simply looking at the FCC ID code on the back of the controller: the code ends with "**1**" on the first model and with "**A**" on the new version.

There is an issue with this: to see the code you need to have an already unboxed controller.
I am therefore wondering if anyone documented some tell-by that can be applied to a ***boxed*** controller in a shop in order to recognize the controller version.

Apparently some models only exist in the new model (ex: the Pink dualsense)... but what about the old plain white and black ones? Can you tell apart a new model from an old one just by looking at the box?